# Python Subprocess.Run inserting escape characters into program arguments

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, escaping

```
subprocess.run([program,'-force-gfx-jobs native -token='+PHPSESSID+ ' -config={"BackendURL":"https://prod.app.com","Version","live"}'])
```

When this command is run and you took in task manager at the command line values passed to the program the double quotes are prefixed by backslashes like this

```
subprocess.run([program,'-force-gfx-jobs native -token='+PHPSESSID+ ' -config={\"BackendURL\":\"https://prod.app.com\",\"Version\",\"live\"}'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a single string where you should be passing a list of strings.

```py
subprocess.run([program,'-force-gfx-jobs', 'native',
     '-token='+PHPSESSID, '-config={"BackendURL":"https://prod.app.com","Version","live"}'])
```

I don't think the displayed backslashes are a problem; they are just for disambiguation (but this is Windows, so I'm probably underestimating the amount of crazy).

Comment: In Windows, every process has to parse its own command line string into arguments, i.e. there is no equivalent of a Unix `argv` array at the OS level. But there are standard [argument parsing rules](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/main-function-command-line-args?view=vs-2019#parsing-c-command-line-arguments) at least that are used by the Windows C runtime library and `CommandLineToArgvW`. When subprocess `args` is a list, `subprocess.list2cmdline` is called to build WinAPI `CreateProcessW` `lpCommandLine` according to these rules, including escaping literal double quote characters.

Comment: If you already have a command line that's prepared according to these rules, or if you need to pass a command line to a process that uses different rules (e.g. Cygwin programs follow Unix shell rules), then it makes more sense in Windows to simply pass subprocess `args` as a string. Don't try to manually parse the command line into a list just to have `subprocess.list2cmdline` rebuild it, potentially in a way that won't work.